# Remove rows with a certain value in any column in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am working in pyspark to clean a data set. The data set has "?" in various rows in various columns. I want to remove any row that has the value anywhere in it. I tried the following:

df = df.replace("?", "np.Nan")
df=df.dropna()

However, It did not work to remove those values.

I keep looking online but can't find any understandable answers (i am a newbie)